# Destructor for CArray takes about 30 seconds to run

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, mfc

I'm curious if someone could explain to me why when I call a destructor on the following array:

```
CArray<READ_ENTRY> arr;
```

It takes about 30 seconds to finish?

The `arr` array at the time has about 240,000 entries, which I thought wasn't that many. Also to compare memory usage, I took the working set from the Task Manager for my process before that array is filled in and after, and the working set grew by about 322 MB.

Also if there's something that I can do to optimize/speed it up?

**EDIT:**

The data that is being stored in this array is distributed as such:

- CString members contain relatively short strings that are between 10 to 300 `wchar`s long.
- My `MEM_ARRAY` byte arrays also contain relatively small amounts of data:

  - `procPrivs` is about 20-100 bytes on average.
  - `userSID` is even smaller, it's the size of the user's SID (no more than 50 bytes.)
- The rest are just 4 or 8 byte members.

**EDIT2:** In Release build it takes exactly the same amount of time to run.

The following structures are defined as such:

```
struct READ_ENTRY{
    DWORD flags;
    FILETIME ftLogTimeUTC;
    short wTimeDiffMin;

    int nOSErrorCode;
    int nSpecCode;

    DWORD dwMessageID;
    DWORD dwMessageCtr;
    DWORD dwMessageAllowBackSecs;

    BYTE wProductType;
    DWORD dwOSType;
    DWORD dwMajorVersion;
    DWORD dwMinorVersion;
    DWORD dwBuildNumber;
    WORD wServicePackMajor;
    WORD wServicePackMinor;
    WORD wSuiteMask;
    WORD wProcessorArchitecture;
    ULONGLONG dwActiveProcessorMask;

    DWORD dwProcID;
    DWORD dwThreadID;
    LCID lcidThread;

    MEM_ARRAY procPrivs;

    CString strUserName;
    MEM_ARRAY userSID;

    CString strModName;

    CString strMsgTitle;
    CString strMsgDesc;

    READ_ENTRY()
    {
        flags = DBXF_NONE;
        ftLogTimeUTC.dwLowDateTime = 0;
        ftLogTimeUTC.dwHighDateTime = 0;
        wTimeDiffMin = 0;

        nOSErrorCode = 0;
        nSpecCode = 0;

        dwMessageID = 0;
        dwMessageCtr = 0;
        dwMessageAllowBackSecs = 0;

        wProductType = 0;
        dwOSType = 0;
        dwMajorVersion = 0;
        dwMinorVersion = 0;
        dwBuildNumber = 0;
        wServicePackMajor = 0;
        wServicePackMinor = 0;
        wSuiteMask = 0;
        wProcessorArchitecture = 0;
        dwActiveProcessorMask = 0;

        dwProcID = 0;
        dwThreadID = 0;
        lcidThread = NULL;
    }
};
```

and:

```
struct MEM_ARRAY{
    BYTE* pMem;
    int ncbSzMem;

    MEM_ARRAY() :
        pMem(NULL)
        , ncbSzMem(0)
    {
    }
    ~MEM_ARRAY()
    {
        freeMem();
    }
    MEM_ARRAY(BYTE* pSrcSID, int ncbSz) :
        pMem(NULL)
        , ncbSzMem(0)
    {
        copyMem(pSrcSID, ncbSz);
    }
    MEM_ARRAY(const MEM_ARRAY& s) :
        pMem(NULL)
        , ncbSzMem(0)
    {
        copyMem(s.pMem, s.ncbSzMem);
    }
    MEM_ARRAY& operator = (const MEM_ARRAY& s)
    {
        copyMem(s.pMem, s.ncbSzMem);
        return *this;
    }

    void freeMem()
    {
        if(pMem)
        {
            delete[] pMem;
            pMem = NULL;
        }

        ncbSzMem = 0;
    }

    void copyMem(BYTE* pSrcSID, int ncbSz)
    {
        if(pSrcSID != pMem)
        {
            freeMem();

            pMem = new (std::nothrow) BYTE[ncbSz];
            ASSERT(pMem);
            if(pMem)
            {
                memcpy(pMem, pSrcSID, ncbSz);
                ncbSzMem = ncbSz;
            }
        }
        else
            ASSERT(ncbSz == ncbSzMem);
    }
};
```

**EDIT3:** Here's a sample of how to fill in the array:

```
#define SIZEOF(f) (sizeof(f) / sizeof(f[0]))

{
CArray<READ_ENTRY> arr;

BYTE dummy[256];
srand((UINT)time(NULL));
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(dummy); i++)
    dummy[i] = (BYTE)rand();

READ_ENTRY re;

arr.SetSize(240000);    //Optimize it, since we know the final size

for(int t = 0; t < 240000; t++)
{
    static LPCTSTR words[] = {
        L"success",  L"added",  L"new", L"entry",
        L"didn't",  L"counter", L"as",  L"ran",
        L"out",  L"this",   L"first",   L"because",
        L"the",  L"just",   L"error",   L"if",
        L"or",  L"manually",    L"simple",  L"program",
        L"how",  L"what",   L"title",   L"great",
    };


    CString strTitle;
    int nCntW = GetRandomNumber(0, 12);
    for(int i = 0; i < nCntW; i++)
    {
        if(!strTitle.IsEmpty())
            strTitle += L" ";

        strTitle += words[GetRandomNumber(0, SIZEOF(words))];
    }

    CString strDesc;
    int nCntWDesc = GetRandomNumber(0, 100);
    for(int i = 0; i < nCntWDesc; i++)
    {
        if(!strDesc.IsEmpty())
            strDesc += L" ";

        strDesc += words[GetRandomNumber(0, SIZEOF(words))];
    }

    re.strMsgTitle = strTitle;  //Use some randomness for these members
    re.strMsgDesc = strDesc;

    re.strModName = L"Test Module v.1.0.0.0";
    re.strUserName = L"mycomputername\\my user name";

    re.procPrivs.copyMem(dummy, GetRandomNumber(10, 100));
    re.userSID.copyMem(dummy, GetRandomNumber(10, 50));

    arr.SetAtGrow(t, re);
}

//Destructor will be called here
}


ULONG GetRandomNumber(ULONG nNumMin, ULONG nNumMax)
{
    ULONG nMin, nMax;
    if(nNumMin <= nNumMax)
    {
        nMin = nNumMin;
        nMax = nNumMax;
    }
    else
    {
        nMin = nNumMax;
        nMax = nNumMin;
    }

    ULONG nRnd = ((ULONG)(rand() & 0x7fff) << 17) | 
        ((ULONG)(rand() & 0x7fff) << 2) |
        ((ULONG)(rand() & 0x3));

    return nMax > nMin ? (nRnd % (nMax - nMin)) + nMin : nMin;
}
```

Comment: There are a few things that look fishy with your code, but none of them look seriously wrong. So, question remains how to reproduce the issue that you have, and for that you haven't provided enough info. Also, do you run this with a memory debugger active, which is the default in MSVC's debug mode? This is one thing that costs time. If that isn't it, compare with the creation and destruction of a plain array and use a profiler to find out what's taking so long.

Comment: The `MEM_ARRAY` is ungood, in particular the general idea, but also details such as copy constructor. Replace with `std::vector`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Can you explain what's "ungood" about it?

Comment: It starts with the name, which suggests a macro. Then, it's reproducing things that a `std::vector` or even `CArray` already provide. It's not exception-safe. It contains unsafe code because its members are not properly encapsulated. It lacks const-correctness. It is undocumented. It uses assertions in places where it should use error handling and doesn't use them where it should.

Comment: @c00000fd: It's ungood because it's a DIY solution, introducing a lot of possibly buggy extra code and raw access to implementation, to do what the standard library does guaranteed correctly for you. Unless its purpose is to ensure a binary memory layout. And in the case of binary memory layout, are you sure that all code that sets that pointer uses `new`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: OK. And how exactly does all that affect performance?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Sure. It's my own implementation. If you suggest something else instead of my `MEM_ARRAY` I can try that and see if it improves performance?

Comment: Nobody here claimed that this code is necessarily slow. You still need to profile the code to find out what's taking so long. Also, I still vote to close this question because you haven't provided the necessary code to reproduce the issue - the amount of work for doing something on a container also depends on its content.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Do you want me to upload 322 MB of data too.

Comment: Are 321 MB also enough to reproduce the unexpected slowdown? 1 MB? Can you create test data algorithmically to show the slowdown?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Fair enough. I updated my answer. As for 1 MB array, then it is freed at no time. The performance in this case goes down exponentially with the number of entries in the array.

Comment: The problem is probably in the other code that you still have not provided. Do you really expect to understand this problem if you don't reproduce it in isolation and without measuring (not guessing, like "at no time" and "exponential") the actual influences? Sorry if this sounds harsh, but such is the reality of technical problems.

Comment: @c00000fd: As others mentioned, try first of all to **generate the data** algorithmically, so that you can post a small but complete example here that folks can try. But also do replace the MEM_ARRAY with a `std::vector<Byte>`. See if that doesn't help (maybe it does, maybe not).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thanks. I dug a little bit into it and it seems that the answer below is close to the truth. As I noted above, this question is not about filling up the array but about freeing it. And what it looks like, the `delete` operator that is called implicitly for 6 members of my `READ_ENTRY` struct, plus 1 time for that struct itself is what's causing this performance degradation. It other words, it causes approx. `7 * 240,000` calls to `delete` or whatever MFC uses for `CString` & `CArray`. That seems to be the issue...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I posted a code sample that should fill in the array with some random data to imitate what I see. I'm testing it on a 32-bit process under VS 2008.

Comment: @c00000fd: I collected the code in one file, http://pastebin.com/ywH0Yvjb, compiled (using Visual C++ 19.00.22310.1) and run. Unable to reproduce. Cleanup was sort of instant.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I'm not doing it in the Pastebin. I'm testing it on my actual development machine.

Comment: @c00000fd: pastebin,com doesn't support compilation, so it's not surprising that you're not doing your testing there.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem happening in release build too? (I cant comment it seems noobs dont get enough reputation to comment). what platform?

If the slow down is there in release build as well and you are seeing CPU spikes on delete then you might want to fix your data structures, at the risk of stating the obvious you'r heap is being stressed out. Freeing large amount of memory is a highly CPU intensive task.

You can ... Try clubbing the memory blocks into a larger block. Use fixed length strings, it will cause external fragmentation but you can decide where to draw the line.

One approach is to have the Carray per CPU and a separate heap for each one of them. This will make allocation and deallocation more concurrent.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Please don't abuse answers just to post a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your take on it. I just tried it in Release build and it takes exactly the same amount of time.

Comment: yes, I didnt know the etiquette here. humble apologies. I will remember this in future.